# Pure CSS scroll-snap only works with the body as the container

Tags: html, css, web, scroll

I am trying to set up a **snapping scroll with pure css**.

With the **snapping scroll there is a container for all the elements over which the snapping scroll is active containing the elements which the scroll snaps onto.

When I am using the **body-tag as the container** and elements with the class "section", everything **works fine**:

```css
body {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.section {
    height: calc(100vh - 14em);
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 7em;
    margin: 0;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.section:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 30%);
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: hsl(40, 100%, 30%);
}

.section:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: hsl(50, 100%, 30%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scroll-Snap Body</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scrollsnap_body.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="section">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid aspernatur eius est fuga inventore
       officia possimus quibusdam recusandae sunt. Adipisci blanditiis corporis cupiditate dolorem ducimus
       excepturi laboriosam officia quae vero.</p>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <p>Accusamus amet dicta dolorum fugiat id itaque iure minus molestiae nesciunt non omnis quibusdam, veniam!
       Animi, aspernatur consectetur doloremque ducimus illum perferendis quam ut? Aspernatur deserunt doloremque
       error magnam minima.</p>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <p>Ab accusantium aut corporis, cumque dolor ducimus ea est, excepturi facere, fuga id labore magni minima nemo
       odio officia officiis quaerat quibusdam quo sit tempora tenetur unde veritatis! Doloremque, nam.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use a **separate div with class "container"** as the container it **doesn't work**:

```css
body {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}

.container {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0;
}

.section {
    height: calc(100vh - 14em);
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 7em;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.section:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 30%);
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: hsl(40, 100%, 30%);
}

.section:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: hsl(50, 100%, 30%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scroll-Snap Container</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scrollsnap_container.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="section">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid aspernatur eius est fuga inventore
           officia possimus quibusdam recusandae sunt. Adipisci blanditiis corporis cupiditate dolorem ducimus
           excepturi laboriosam officia quae vero.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <p>Accusamus amet dicta dolorum fugiat id itaque iure minus molestiae nesciunt non omnis quibusdam, veniam!
           Animi, aspernatur consectetur doloremque ducimus illum perferendis quam ut? Aspernatur deserunt doloremque
           error magnam minima.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <p>Ab accusantium aut corporis, cumque dolor ducimus ea est, excepturi facere, fuga id labore magni minima nemo
           odio officia officiis quaerat quibusdam quo sit tempora tenetur unde veritatis! Doloremque, nam.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. By default, the `<body>` element has a fixed height of `100vh`. You just need to add the same to your `container` class.

```
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

That gives the scroll something to snap to. Otherwise, the `<div class="container">` will have a height equal to that of all the child elements combined, which doesn't give the scroll a fixed window to snap to.

Likewise, if you were doing horizontal scrolling, you'd need to provide your container with a fixed width.